# Fastlane passing parameters to plugin

Tags: android, android-emulator, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I am using Fastlane plugin automated_test_emulator_run

```
automated_test_emulator_run(
    AVD_setup_path: "~/<path to your avd setup>/AVD_setup.json",
//some more tasks
  )
```

now trying to run this same via command line

```
fastlane automated_test_emulator_run AVD_setup_path:avd.json
```

but getting eror

[!] Could not find 'automated_test_emulator_run'. Available lanes: test

any hint to use any plugin and pass setup parameters for that?

Answer (score 12):

I haven't done exactly this but have done something similar so following should work I believe:

```
lane :your_emulator_lane do |options|
    avdSetupPath = options[:AVD_setup_path]

    automated_test_emulator_run(
        AVD_setup_path: avdSetupPath,
    )

end
```

Would then call

```
fastlane your_emulator_lane AVD_setup_path:avd.json
```

Comment: Thanks for help. same I am doing. I do not want to use file for lane setup

Comment: setting a Jenkins pipeline job, Jenkins pipeline does not support android emulator.
a repository may not have Fastlane file and a user can input custom emulator configuration on runtime

Comment: found solution:
fastlane run automated_test_emulator_run AVD_setup_path:"avd.json"